# How to establish connect/disconnect event handlers in class that utilizes the blink1 HidLibrary?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to detect two events for this particular USB device (blink1): insert and remove

I've successfully enumerated the device(s) and can send commands, though I'm having a difficult time establishing the delegates and getting either event to trigger.

The [HidLibrary.cs](https://github.com/todbot/blink1/blob/master/windows/ManagedBlink1/HidLibrary/HidDevice.cs) library contains two event handlers titled "InsertedEventHandler", "RemovedEventHandler" and the functions "DeviceEventMonitorInserted", "DeviceEventMonitorRemoved" which seem to be attached to an instance of the [HidDeviceEventMonitor.cs](https://github.com/todbot/blink1/blob/master/windows/ManagedBlink1/HidLibrary/HidDeviceEventMonitor.cs) class. I'm attempting to establish connect/disconnect/re-connect methods within the calling class where I utilize the HidLibrary class as:

```
using HidLibrary
...
private HidDevice hidDevice;
...
hidDevice.command(var1, var2, ..);
```

I feel this is a simple task, and I've established and worked with event handlers, routed events and delegates in the past to a limited degree in C# but I seem to be missing a crucial concept when dealing with this particular situation.

**Update**: In case anyone else comes across this when working with the blink1 HidLibrary, to enable the EventMonitor you must set `hidDevice.MonitorDeviceEvents = true` after calling OpenDevice() on the HidDevice instance. This isn't in any of the documentation and only became apparent after getting the event routing down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any Blink1 devices, but after spending a few minutes with the code, I think this might work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    HidDevice device;

    // device declaration

    device.Inserted += Device_Inserted;
    device.Removed += Device_Removed;
}

private static void Device_Removed()
{
    // Some stuff to do when device is removed
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static void Device_Inserted()
{
    // Some stuff to do when device is inserted
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and similar to other variations I had attempted, and does work although in my particular case there was a catch I was not able to track down until I started using your suggestion. I'm accepting this answer and updating the original question. Thank you!